# Convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+nx)^n}{n!} , x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have been trying this question

$\frac{(1+nx)^n}{n!} > \frac{(nx)^n}{n!}$

Since
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(nx)^n}{n!}$ is divergent when $x \geq \frac{1}{e} \implies 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}   \frac{(1+nx)^n}{n!}  $ is divergent.

I don't know how to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}   \frac{(1+nx)^n}{n!}$ is convergent for $0<x < \frac{1}{e} $

Help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It does not diverge for $x=0$. What exactly do you need to prove?

Comment: I want to prove that it converge for $0<x<\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: If you know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(nx)^n}{n!}$ is convergent at $0<x<\frac1{e}$, then you can use $(\frac{1+nx}{nx})^n < e^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

Comment: $\lim \sup a_n^{1/n} =e$ by Stirling's formula.

Comment: (1). Stirling's Formula ... (2). $(1+nx)^n=n^nx^n(1+1/nx)^n$ and $(1+1/nx)^n\to  e^{1/x}.$

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good beginning. 
$0 < x < \frac{1}{e}$
$\implies 1 < (1+xn) < \frac{n}{e} + 1 $
$\implies 1 < (1+xn)^{n} < (\frac{n}{e} + 1)^{n} \\$
$\implies 1 < \frac{(1+xn)^{n}}{n!} <\frac{(n + e)^{n}}{n!e^{n}}$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "d'Alembert's ratio test" which says, let
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}| = k$$
if
$k>1$, then series is divergent, $k<1$, then series is convergent, else test is inconclusive.

In this case,
$$U_n = \frac{(1+nx)^n}{n!}$$
Then
$$k = \lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{(1+(n+1)x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{(1+nx)^n}|$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}|[\frac{1+(n+1)x}{1+nx}]^n\frac{1+(n+1)x}{n+1}|$$

Using the fact that $x<1$ and applying algebra of limits we get,
$$k = \lim_{n \to \infty}|[\frac{1+(n+1)x}{1+nx}]^n|\lim_{x \to \infty}|\frac{1+(n+1)x}{n+1}|$$

Note that the second limit reduces to x. For the first limit we let

$$L = \lim_{n \to \infty}|[\frac{1+(n+1)x}{1+nx}]^n|$$
Taking natural log both sides and simplifying the equation we get
$$\ln(L) = \lim_{n \to \infty}n|\ln(1+\frac{1+x}{nx})-\ln(1+\frac{1}{nx})|$$
Now this limit is easy to obtain just by using power series expansion of  $\ln(1+x)$ which gives us $L$ = e

So we get
$$k = e|x|$$
And by the condition for convergence
$$k=e|x|<1$$
$$\implies |x|<\frac{1}{e}$$.